# Declaring sparse matrix is too slow

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, finite-element-analysis

I'm currently working on FEM with matlab.

my code is like this

```
function [A,rhs] = Assemble()

pre_process();
[IA,JA,A,rhs] = assemble(pre_processed_parameters); // mex-func
// IA : row index 
// JA : col index
//  A : value

A = sparse(IA,JA,A);
```

When `A` is size of `ten million x ten million`,

`pre_process` takes less than 1 second

`assemble` takes about 5 seconds

`sparse` takes about 820 sec

The major time consuming line is a single line `sparse`.

Is there any faster way to collect it?

Properties of `IA`, `JA` and `A` are

1. Pair of `(IA[k],JA[k])` have all distinct values for all `k`.
2. resulting matrix, `A`, is lower triangular and have block structure

Comment: How many elements do you actually have in your sparse matrix? i.e. what is `numel(IA)`?

Comment: Upgrade your computer? Given the number of elements that doesn't seem slow and without more information on the data it's pretty much impossible to answer the optimization question.

Comment: `nnz` is 855,582,720. I found `fsparse` in user.it.uu.se/~stefane/freeware.html. This makes sparse declaration twice faster.

Comment: Maybe they do not use Compressed Row/Column Storage format (which is the format you are using). Google it and have a look at : https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/otherdocs/simax.pdf